# Parsing QR returned string in java

Tags: java

I am reading QR through camera and returning the string which that QR returns.
I am parsing that string to decode that value. Please look at the code and sample input and output data.

Code:

```
public void decodeQRString()
{
    String alphaNumeric = "123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String str = "0F123456789ABCDEF1OABERCROMBIE SUBWAY SHOP241234";
    int n = str.length(), i = 0;

    while(i < n)
    {
        StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();

        int len = alphaNumeric.indexOf(str.charAt(i+1)) + 1;

        int l = len + 1;
        for(int j = 2; j <= l; j++)
        {
            tmp.append(str.charAt(i+j));
        }
        System.out.println(str.charAt(i) + ":" + str.charAt(i+1) + ":" + tmp.toString());
        i = (i+2) + len;
    }
}
```

Required Output:

```
0:F:123456789ABCDEF

1:O:ABERCROMBIE SUBWAY SHOP

2:4:1234
```

My Output:

```
0:F:123456789ABCDEF

1:O:ABERCROMBIE SUBWAY SHOP2

4:1:2
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: I get the following output:

`0:F:123456789ABCDEF
G:H:1OABERCROMBIE SUB
W:A:Y SHOP2412` + **StringIndexOutOfBoundsException** ... edit your code to correspond to reality ...

Comment: can you explain the encoding used in the string? Would make it much easier to come up with a solution than letting us guess the rules from an incorrect program.

Comment: The rules is First Character 0 is index, F is the length of the string, next f characters

Comment: Rule is Index:StringLength:String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me, your program is OK and the encoding of the string is incorrect. Instead of

```
"0F123456789ABCDEF1OABERCROMBIE SUBWAY SHOP241234"
```

it should be

```
"0F123456789ABCDEF1NABERCROMBIE SUBWAY SHOP241234"
```

Because the length of `ABERCROMBIE SUBWAY SHOP` corresponds to `N` and not `O`.

Comment: Actually i get that string by scanning QR. But O is correct instead of N. Could you help me in code here.

Comment: if the second letter specifies the length as you have specified, it is not correct independent where you got it from.